# JavaScript charting library for advanced charting

Tags: javascript, charts

**Background to Question:**

Software for analysing blood glucose readings for diabetics, typically have something called a "daily modal" chart.

This chart type is a line chart showing times of day on the X-axis, blood glucose readings on the Y-axis, and it displays this for a specified date range. So for example, I can see a chart of my daughter's readings over, say, the last week - with each day's readings superimposed on the single chart (this is the key -- superimposing each day's blood glucose readings on the same time-of-day based chart). It's the best way to see trends by time of day. If there is, in addition, a trend line showing the averages by time of day over the given time period, even better.

**The Question:**

Does anyone know of a JavaScript charting library that would allow me to build such a chart? I'm wondering if Flot does, or the Google visualization API for example?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you even tried a proof-of-concept with Flot? Based on what I know about it, it certainly seems like it'd be capable of at least getting close to what you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take a look at a loooot of such libraries at once, from helicopter point of view, and choose which one (or few) can draw what you need:

[28 Rich Data Visualization Tools](http://1styearinfo.pbworks.com/f/28RichDataVisualizationTools.pdf)

I hope it brings you enough opportunities to get job done ;)

**UPDATE:**
I fixed link above, because InsideRIA is no longer an active site, as of January 31, 2011.
Also,list of new charting libraries, which use HTML5 canvas feature can be found here:

[HTML5 Canvas Graphing Solutions Every Web Developers Must Know](http://webdesigneraid.com/html5-canvas-graphing-solutions-every-web-developers-must-know/)

Comment: The link given to 28 'Rich Data Visualization Tools'(http://www.developria.com/2009/12/28-rich-data-visualization-too.html) looks unavaialble, the links goes to http://www.adobe.com/devnet.html

Comment: @gnanz: thanks, I've managed to find that article backed up somewhere else, please check a link again, should be working, at least for some time :)

Answer (score 2):

Another capable javascript charting library: http://g.raphaeljs.com/

Answer (score 1):

Google chart api does this.  You can access it very easily with JS.

http://code.google.com/apis/chart/docs/gallery/line_charts.html

You'll have to do all the math, though.