# HTML5 chart library to plot multiple graphs at the same canvas

Tags: javascript, html, graph, html5-canvas

The task is to draw multiple charts at the same canvas. RGraph works ok for me, but it becomes a problem, when I add labels. It doesn't do smart computations and labels may overlap, which makes graph ugly and unreadable.

If you encountered the same task and was able to solve it, please, share the library it can be done with.

Comment: Here's 28 of them: http://www.developria.com/2009/12/28-rich-data-visualization-too.html. This question is likely to be closed as it's been asked many times over.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript charting library for advanced charting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355890/javascript-charting-library-for-advanced-charting)